# load custom font into html (webview) - metro app

Tags: c#, html, css, fonts, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a metro app: c# and xaml.
The app loads a html file (stored in a directory) into a webview with its css file. 
I want to use a custom font: how can I accompish that?

I've tried

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Geeza_Pro';
    src: url('ms-appx-web:///Fonts/Geeza_Pro.ttf') format('truetype');
    }


#div_name{
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: "Geeza_Pro";
}
```

and

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Geeza_Pro';
    src: url('Fonts/Geeza_Pro.ttf') format('truetype');
    }


#div_name{
    font-size:30px;
    font-family: "Geeza_Pro";
```

but is doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

```
@font-face /* Define New Font */
{
    font-family: coolfont; /* Assign Font Name */
    src: url('fonts/coolfont.ttf'); /* Font File Location */
}

#div_name
{
    font-family: coolfont;
}
```

Comment: Double check the position of your running code against the src specified in your css. Be sure you are pointing the correct folder.

Comment: my font is in /Fonts/font.ttf and my html and css are in /Assets/WebView. Am I referring right to the font?

Comment: Try '../Fonts/Geeza_Pro.ttf'.

Comment: It MUST have something to do with your current location.